# Overwrite Cursor Position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a function that overwrites the e.clientY and e.clientX when i hover on the navbar so that the cursor would be in the middle of the background circle. Can anybody please help?

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector('#cursor');

        document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
        cursor.setAttribute("style", "top: " + (e.clientY - 10) + "px; left: " + (e.clientX - 10) + "px;")
        })
        document.getElementById("navbarimg").addEventListener("mouseover",function(e) {
        cursor.classList.toggle("hover")
        })
        document.getElementById("navbarimg").addEventListener("mouseout",function(e) {
        cursor.classList.toggle("hover")
        })
```

```css
body{margin:0;height:100vh;background:rgb(27,27,27);}
            #cursor{width:30px;height:30px;border:2px solid gray;border-radius:50%;position:fixed;transition-duration: 100ms;transition-timing-function: ease-out;}
            #navbarimg{position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform:tranlate(-50%,-50%);}
            #cursor.hover{width:100px;height:100px;opacity:0.1;background-color:gray;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Cursor</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="cursor"></div>
            <div class="nav">
            <a href="../"><img id="navbarimg"  src="navbar.svg" alt="navbar"></a>           </div>
      </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` to the cursor and no need any offset

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector('#cursor');

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  cursor.setAttribute("style", "top: " + (e.clientY) + "px; left: " + (e.clientX ) + "px;")
})
document.getElementById("navbarimg").addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
  cursor.classList.toggle("hover")
})
document.getElementById("navbarimg").addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {
  cursor.classList.toggle("hover")
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgb(27, 27, 27);
}

#cursor {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition-duration: 100ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

#navbarimg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#cursor.hover {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0.1;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Cursor</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cursor"></div>
  <div class="nav">
    <a href="../"><img id="navbarimg" src="navbar.svg" alt="navbar"></a>
  </div>
</body>
```